# Trying to identify source of error shown in Chrome JavaScript Console

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I'm using the latest version of Chrome (14.0.x) to debug my javascript (latest jQuery) as well as manipulate CSS.  As of a few versions ago of Chrome, I am always getting the following error in the JavaScript Console.  Does anyone have any idea how I can track down the source of this error in my code?

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at handleGetResources (chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/ContentScript.js:12:70)
    at chrome/RendererExtensionBindings:239:13
    at [object Object].dispatch (chrome/EventBindings:181:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome/RendererExtensionBindings:141:22)
```

and the file it points to is "chrome/EventBindings:183"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.  It isn't in my code, but in one of the Extensions I installed.  I disabled all the extensions and saw that the error went away, then started adding the extensions in one by one.  FYI, the offending Extension was "SiteAdvisor - Version: 3.31.137.7"

Comment: Bingo!! I have the same error and disabling Site Advisor v3.31.137.7 fixed the problem.